# SQL - insert into data1,data2 new values that not indexed into any table

Tags: mysql

i want to

```
insert into player table (col1,col2,col3) 
    values(data1,data2,select clubs.club_id
    from club
    where clubs.club_name='elahly' )
```

**note:** data1, data2 are not defined or copied from any table its a new values .

**UPDATED:**

when i tried to insert my values in these query:

```
INSERT INTO add_new_player (first_name, full_name,club_name,team,birthday,gender,weight,kata_kumite,individual_collective,
                            heavey_light,belt_color
                            ,country,country_flags,date_of_admission)SELECT 
'على','علا',

clubs.club_id,
'team.team_id',
'2000',
'ذكر',
'0',
'ابيض',
countries.country_id,'eg',
'2015-07-26 11:43:24'

    FROM clubs inner join team on team.team_name='0' inner join countries on countries.country_name='قطر'
   and clubs.club_name='elahly'
```

it gave me the result :

```
0 rows inserted. (Query took 0.0007 sec)
```

why no rows inserted where is the problem .

Comment: We get that the SQL doesn't work.  Try editing your question with sample data and desired results to explain what you want to actually do.

Comment: @GordonLinoff i updated my question why no rows inserted why this happened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
INSERT INTO `your-table` (col1,col2,col3)
    SELECT 'newvalue1','newvalue2', clubs.club_id
    FROM club
    WHERE clubs.club_name='elahly';
```

**Update**:

Formatted your query:

```
INSERT INTO add_new_player
(
    first_name,
    full_name,
    club_name,
    team,
    birthday,
    gender,
    weight,
    kata_kumite,
    individual_collective,
    heavey_light,
    belt_color,
    country,
    country_flags,
    date_of_admission
)
SELECT 
    'على',
    'علا',
    clubs.club_id,
    'team.team_id',
    '2000',
    'ذكر',
    '0',
    'كاتا',
    'جماعى',
    'خفيف',
    'ابيض',
    countries.country_id,
    'eg',
    '2015-07-26 11:43:24'
FROM clubs 
INNER JOIN team ON team.team_name='0' 
INNER JOIN countries ON countries.country_name='قطر'
AND clubs.club_name='elahly'
```

Make sure your SELECT query is returning rows, and that your inserting the right data types.

Comment: i updated my question why no rows inserted why this happened?

Comment: Run your SELECT query by itself, is it returning data? Also make sure the number of fields are the same.

Answer (score 1):

You rather need to use `INSERT INTO .. SELECT FROM` construct like

```
insert into `player table` (col1,col2,col3) 
    SELECT data1, data2, club_id
    from club
    where club_name = 'elahly';
```

Comment: i updated my question why no rows inserted why this happened?